# URL redirect in tomcat project

Tags: .htaccess, tomcat, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am doing a web project using tomcat 7.0 . I want to redirect one page to another page.

Can I use .htaccess file in tomcat? If it can be used, how can I do?

Or can I config in web.xml ?

I'm appreciate for your helps.

Best regards,

Sokly

Answer (score 0):

`mod_rewrite` is only an Apache module but you can use [**`UrlRewriteFilter`**](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) in Tomcat.

A rule like this should work for you in `/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml`:

```
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <note>
            The rule means that requests to /page-one/ will be redirected to /page-two/.
            The url will be rewritten.
        </note>
        <from>/page-one/</from>
        <to type="redirect">/page-two/</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```